# how to get value from this slider and how to make a new same slider?

Tags: jquery

here is the code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<title>jQuery UI Slider </title>
<link href="../style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
        <style type="text/css"> 
#container{
background:url(bg.jpg)!important;
padding:100px 50px 0px 50px;
}

/*the slider background*/
.slider {
width:230px;
height:11px;
background:url(slider-bg.png);
position:relative;
margin:0;
padding:0 10px;
}

/*Style for the slider button*/
.ui-slider-handle {
width:24px;
height:24px;
position:absolute;
top:-7px;
margin-left:-12px;
z-index:200;

}

/*Result div where the slider value is displayed*/
#slider-result {
font-size:20px;
height:200px;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color:#fff;
width:250px;
text-align:center;
text-shadow:0 1px 1px #000;
font-weight:700;
padding:20px 0;
}

/*This is the fill bar colour*/
.ui-widget-header {
background:url(fill.png) no-repeat left;
height:8px;
left:1px;
top:1px;
position:absolute;
}

a {
outline:none;
-moz-outline-style:none;
}


        </style> 
</head>
<body>




        <div class="slider"></div> 

        <div class="slider1"></div> 

        <div class="slider2"></div> 

        <div id="slider-result" value="poor">Poor</div>   
        <div id="slider-result1" value="poor">Poor</div>   
        <input type="hidden" value="poor" id="hidden"/>
        <input type="hidden1" value="poor" id="hidden"/>

           <script> 

                 $( ".slider" ).slider({
                animate: true,
                range: "min",
                value: 0,
                min: 0,
                max: 4,
                step: 1,

                //this gets a live reading of the value and prints it on the page
                slide: function( event, ui ) {
                if(ui.value ==0)
                    $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Poor");
                    else if(ui.value == 1)
                    $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Average");
                    else if(ui.value == 2)
                    $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Good");
                    else if(ui.value == 3)
                    $( "#slider-result" ).html( " Very Good");
                    else if(ui.value == 4)
                    $( "#slider-result" ).html( "Excellent");

                },

                //this updates the hidden form field so we can submit the data using a form
                change: function(event, ui) { 
                $('#hidden').attr('value', ui.value);

                }

                });


        </script> 




</body>
</html>
```

How to get the value of selected slider? Since it is hidden when i get the value using
`var currentValue = $('#hidden').val();`, I get an object as return value. i could not get that value... any help and also want to make a new same slider in     `<div class="slider1"></div>`  to make it?

Any idea?

Comment: You'll get a better/quicker response with a jsfiddle.net example, fyi.

Comment: @Phil i could not get that value from slider. how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure about that second part.  Could you be a little clearer?

On the value bit you could try $(selector).attr('value').

Comment: Good! Can we have a little more details on the second bit?  What are you trying to do with the extra slider?  Clone the value or....?

Comment: how to clone that slider element??

Comment: As noted below you can use clone() to get an exact copy.  Is that what you are wanting?  If so what is the trigger and purpose of making an exact copy of an already usable slider?

Answer (score 0):

you can clone an element in jquery with clone(), like
$("#whatever").clone().appendTo("#container")
would clone the element with id 'whatever' and insert it at the end of element 'container' (which could be a `<div`> for example)